# SSC TLE5012B read out

Tags: sensor, spi

I have some trouble with understanding the following IC and its SSC interface:

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE5012B_Exxxx-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a304334fac4c601350f31c43c433f

It is stated in the datasheet, that the SSC interface is SPI compatible, exactly what I need. Now first of all, how should I connect this SSC interface to an SPI interface? Can I do it as follows:

**SSC** -> **SPI**

CSQ -> SS

SCK -> SCK

DATA -> MOSI/MISO shorted together

Second, I'm not even sure if I can read out the absolute angular position of this sensor over the SSC interface alone, also I cannot find any list with all the available registers I can read/write to. I think this normally should be included in the datasheet. On the website of Infenion are no more datasheets available, that specifies this SSC registers. Anyone an Idea where this could be hidden?

Comment: Ignore previous comment, looking over the datasheet 2nd time, it's rather confusing.

Comment: You can find the register and protocol info in their user guide (sections 5 and 6).  Note that the SPI interface is a bit tricky in that it's half-duplex.

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/sensor/magnetic-position-sensor/angle-sensor/tle5012b-e5000/#!documents

Select the User Manual drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register and SPI communication protocol details are in the User's Manual, not the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you very much. What's about the SPI to SSC connection, am I right with my assumption? Half duplex should be configurable for an STM32F410CBU6.

Comment: The connections look right to me.